# PostgreSQL concatenate integer and real and add units

Tags: postgresql

I want to concatenate 4 columns in a PostgreSQL query and add units if columns aren't empty.

```
 SELECT
     CASE 
         WHEN a.length_m notnull THEN a.length_m || 'm'
         WHEN a.area_ar notnull THEN a.area_ar || 'ar'
         WHEN a.vol notnull THEN a.vol || 'cbm'
         WHEN a.pcs notnull THEN a.pcs || 'pcs' 
     END as quant;
FROM actions a;
```

This works fine, but if I have values in two colums it only shows me the first one. 
How must I change my query, so that a second WHEN gets evaluated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**COALESCE**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp):

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.length_m ||'m', '') ||
       COALESCE(a.area_ar ||'ar', '') ||
       COALESCE(a.vol ||'cbm', '') ||
       COALESCE(a.pcs ||'pcs', '') as quant
FROM actions a;
```